# how to use NSDictionary in NSUserDefault?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

I want to know how can I use `NSDictionary` in `NSUserDefault` ? I have to store name, points and time of user into the `NSDictionary` and dictionary into the user default.

Comment: I think you need to clarify how the NSDictionary is being used. Is it being used for the entire NSUserDefaults or for a particular entry in the defaults.

Comment: ThomasW : i want to store particular entry in the default with multiple values.

Comment: If the dictionary only contains simple objects like strings and numbers you can, but if it contains your own objects you will need to implement the NSCoding protocol on those first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dict forKey:@"dict"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

At the time of retrieval of data,

```
dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"dict"];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:yourData forKey:@"yourKey"];
[defaults synchronize];

id yourData = [defaults objectForKey:@"yourKey"];
```