# Is good practice to store many values in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, objective-c, entity, nsuserdefaults

For example, I have an entity named `Profile` with attributes like

```
name,
gender,
dateOfBirth,
height,
weight,
bloodGroup,
province,
country,
picture
```

But, I am going to use a single profile for the whole app. So I think I don't need to persist this object into core data. **So is it a good practice to store all attributes in NSUserDefaults?** My app may store other fields in the `NSUserDefaults` too. Is it a good thing to store many values into `NSUserDefaults`? Otherwise any other idea would be appreciated.

Comment: 5 10 value are ok with NSUserDefaults. no problem.

Comment: maybe duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473244/using-nsuserdefaults-to-store-many-values-will-cause-problems/14473435#14473435

Comment: Please check my answer you will get idea about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store values in NSUserDefaults but make sure to add conditions while getting them maybe other users wants to login, like you can erase everything on logout and save on login. Or you can store values in a PList file.

Comment: Can I store data in to plist file dynamically??

Comment: yes you can. plist file is like an xml file, you can store or delete or modify data in it. check the ios dev center there is a tutorial on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSUserDefaults` as there is no information which is confidential, if any information is confidential, you should save values in KeyChain.

You can use `NSDictionary` and store that dictionary directly into `NSUserDefaults`, this will help you access data more easily.

Visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173939/how-to-use-nsdictionary-in-nsuserdefault) link on how to do that.

Hope this info helps you..

Answer (score -2):

iPhone SDK has a very elegant way of saving user settings in a structure called as NSUserDefaults. You can add a bunch of different objects in this UserDefaults – These are nothing but a dictionary of user settings that you will save in the app’s document folder.

Using NSDictionary user can store store data.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary  alloc] init];

[dic addObject:@"name" forKey:@"objProfile"];
[dic addObject:@"gender" forKey:@"objProfile"];

[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] setObject:dic forKey:@"Profile"];
```

Another solution is to store data in `PList`. This is the best way to store data.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I already know how to store dictionary objects and other objects too.. I am asking is it a good practice to store lot of values in a nsuserdefaults

Comment: I have given two answers for you. You can use plist also.

Comment: But still, the original question was about the best practices for NSUserDefaults. Not the best practices for storing settings.